# Erlang :crypto, oid to NamedCurve

Tags: cryptography, erlang, elixir, fido-u2f

When I am decoding a certificate, I get the following data:

```
{:OTPSubjectPublicKeyInfo, {:PublicKeyAlgorithm, {1, 2, 840, 10045, 2, 1}, {:namedCurve, {1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7}}}
```

I know by doing some quick googling that the namedCurve corresponds to `:secp256r1`. However I'm looking for an existing function that can do that translation for me. For example we can find information about the PublicKeyAlgorithm by using the `pkix_sign_types` function. Is there a corresponding function for named curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an undocumented module (marked as private and therefore subject to breaking changes or removal at any time) that has a function which provides bidirectional mapping of namedCurves's values and their names: `pubkey_cert_records:namedCurves/1`:

```
iex(1)> :pubkey_cert_records.namedCurves({1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7})
:secp256r1
iex(2)> :pubkey_cert_records.namedCurves(:secp256r1)
{1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7}
```

I could not find a documented function which allows calling this function with a tuple as argument and getting back an atom.